# Fabric.js: Clear background color of canvas

Tags: fabricjs

Does anyone know how to clear the background color of Fabric.js canvas once you have used the setBackgroundColor method?

I basically want to go back to a "no background color mode" so it will show the div behind.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it with `setBackgroundColor`.

```
canvas.setBackgroundColor('', canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
```

Since the pull request 1445 (https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/pull/1445) is merged you can also set backgroundColor to null.

```
canvas.setBackgroundColor(null, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
```